# Configuring phpMyAdmin - ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user debian-sys-maint'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, webserver, phpmyadmin

I know that this question has already been asked but the answers do not solve my problem.

MySQL-Server version: 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 (Ubuntu)
OS: Kubuntu 20.04 amd64

I have now uninstalled and reinstalled MySQL Server 8.0.
During the first MySQL server installation I was asked for **password validation policy**

[image]

I selected: **level 2 = STRONG**.

Now, after reinstalling MySQL server, when I run `mysql_secure_installation`, the question about "password validation policy" is not asked anymore.
I think this issue is related to the "password validation policy", because after the "Kubuntu 20.04" installation I uninstalled the [KWalletManager](https://apps.kde.org/kwalletmanager5/) and now the passwords can only be stored in plain text, like my WiFi password. I tried to fix this by reinstalling "KWalletManager" but for some reason it did not work.

**How to fix this?**

---

[image: phpMyAdmin Login]

---

**dbconfig-common**

> An error occurred while installing the database: 
>  
>  ERROR 1045
> (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using
> password: YES) . Your options are:
>
> - abort - Causes the operation to fail; you will need to downgrade,
>    reinstall, reconfigure this package, or otherwise
>   manually intervene
>    to continue using it. This will usually also
>   impact your ability to
>    install other packages until the
>   installation failure is resolved.
> - retry - Prompts once more with all the configuration questions
>    (including ones you may have missed due to the debconf priority 
>   setting) and makes another attempt at performing the operation.
> - retry (skip questions) - Immediately attempts the operation again,
>    skipping all questions. This is normally useful only if you
>   have
>    solved the underlying problem since the time the error
>   occurred.
> - ignore - Continues the operation ignoring dbconfig-common errors.
>    This will usually leave this package without a functional
>   database.

---

**The MySQL service runs without errors.**

`systemctl status mysql.service`

> ● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
>  Loaded: loaded
> (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset:
> enabled)
>  Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-05-12 18:23:39
> CEST; 4h 35min ago
>  Main PID: 5410 (mysqld)
>  Status: "Server is
> operational"
>  Tasks: 39 (limit: 16722)
>  Memory: 331.3M
> CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
> └─5410 /usr/sbin/mysqld
>
> Mai 12 18:23:38 anonymous systemd[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDkGN.png): Starting MySQL Community
> Server...
>  Mai 12 18:23:39 anonymous systemd[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDkGN.png): Started MySQL
> Community Server.

---

**The password is encrypted**

`cat etc/mysql/debian.cnf`

> Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
>  [client]
>  host     = localhost
>  user     = debian-sys-maint
> password = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>  socket   =
> /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
>  [mysql_upgrade]
>  host     =
> localhost
>  user     = debian-sys-maint
>  password =
> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>  socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

---

**Log in via Command Line Interface**

`mysql -u root -p`

> Enter password: 
>  Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with
> ; or \g.
>  Your MySQL connection id is 29
>  Server version:
> 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 (Ubuntu)
>  
>  Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
>  
>  Oracle is a registered
> trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
>  affiliates. Other names
> may be trademarks of their respective
>  owners.
>  
>  Type
> 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input
> statement.
>  
>  mysql> \q
> Bye

---

**I can also login without a password.**

`mysql -u root`

> Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
>  Your
> MySQL connection id is 30
>  Server version: 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
> (Ubuntu)
>  
>  Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its
> affiliates.
>  
>  Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle
> Corporation and/or its
>  affiliates. Other names may be trademarks
> of their respective
>  owners.
>  
>  Type 'help;' or '\h' for
> help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
>  
> mysql> \q
> Bye

---

`mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p`

> Enter password: 
>  ERROR 1045
> (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using
> password: YES)

---

`mysql -u debian-sys-maint`

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

---

Comment: "but the answers do not solve my problem" I bet one of them will ;-)  There are  2 possible things: either mysql is not running or the password for debian-sys-maint is wrong. Edit the question by proving mysql runs. The password tends to be in `etc/mysql/debian.cnf` in plain text. Prove from command line you can connect using that password.

Comment: Try these credentials from the command line first to make sure they work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.

The failure was caused by missing of the **avahi-daemon.service**, which I uninstalled after the Kubuntu installation.
Once I reinstalled "avahi-daemon", I had to uninstall the "MySQL-Server" and all associated files, also I had to delete the user "mysql" and the group "mysql", then reinstall MySQL-Server and phpMyAdmin.